# Getting "ValueError: math domain error" in math.pow()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pow

I'm getting

> ValueError: math domain error

while running code like the one below (I simplified it):

```
import math
def f(x):
    return math.pow(x, -4)

for i in range(10):
    print(f(i))
```

Also, I checked type of arguments by

```
for i in range(10):
    print(type(i))
```

Type of `i` is exactly integer.

Comment: Looks like `math.pow` doesn't like negative powers? Not sure if this is a bug or if that's what the docs say. As a workaround you could use `**` operator, i.e. `print(i**-4)`

Comment: This is because the function is raising 0 to the power of -4.  Start the `range` at 1, as `for i in range(1, 10)`.  Zero to *any* power will be zero … it’s a (numerical) domain error.

Comment: @S3DEV Strange though that it throws `domain error` instead of `ZeroDivisionError` which is what you would expect if raising 0 to a negative power. `0**-4` provides a much better error message than `math.pow(0,-4)`